# close ion-fab when clicking outside (vue3/ionic)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, ionic-framework, vuejs3

i'm trying to search a way to close my ion-fab-button when clicking outside this. I saw that It was possible with fab container but im using the last version of ionic and I think its not possible now..
Do you guys know a method to do this  ?

here my template :

```
<ion-fab horizontal="end" vertical="bottom">
    <ion-fab-button color="light">
      <ion-icon class="sizeicon" :icon="happyOutline" />
    </ion-fab-button>
    <ion-fab-list side="top">
      <ion-fab-button>
        <ion-icon :icon="heart" @click="putReaction(roomId, 4)" />
      </ion-fab-button>
      <ion-fab-button>
        <ion-icon :icon="happy" @click="putReaction(roomId, 3)" />
      </ion-fab-button>
      <ion-fab-button>
        <ion-icon :icon="thumbsDownSharp" @click="putReaction(roomId, 2)" />
      </ion-fab-button>
      <ion-fab-button>
        <ion-icon :icon="thumbsUpSharp" @click="putReaction(roomId, 1)" />
      </ion-fab-button>
    </ion-fab-list>
  </ion-fab>
```

and my web view:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found was to click the DOM element manually and do so only if it's active:

`if( fabnode.activated ) fabnode.click();`